# How do I validate if an item uploaded to my server is an image or a video?

Tags: python, django, image, validation, video

I'd only like to store images and videos.
How do I know whether that person uploaded a video or image?

How to verify?

I'm using Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`python-magic`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/0.1) looks like a promising place to start.

Also, for images at least, I've successfully made use of [this snippet](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/1bd00d5eccb87b52/2c817a32aeaa13a5?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=getImageInfo#2c817a32aeaa13a5).